# Removing unwanted characters from the beginning of a sentence using REGEX

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to ignore characters from the beginning of a string until the first valid character appears. The valid characters are `+`, `numbers` and `letters`.

So I my strategy is finding if there are such characters in order to remove them.

I found this to be almost Ok

```
.+?(?=[A-Za-z0-9\+])
```

[Here is the regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Zz8YWc/1)

But this will almost work as it matches perfectly when the string begins with "non valid" characters but gives me a false positive when for some reason the string begins with a valid character and has a length > 1

So the sentence

`abcde`, the `"a"` return as a match and I don't understand why.

How can I solve the puzzle?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Use `.replace(/^[^A-Za-z0-9+]+/, '')`. See https://regex101.com/r/98nRwH/1. The `.+?` matches any char at least once. Also, the pattern matches at any location in the string.

Comment: Are `š` `ç` (etc...) valid characters? Or it depends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.+?` pattern matches any char at least once, so you should not be surprised it matches `a`. Note your pattern can match at any location in the string as you did not use `^` anchor.

You can use

```
.replace(/^[^A-Za-z0-9+]+/, '')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/98nRwH/1). **Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^A-Za-z0-9+]+` - one or more chars other than ASCII letters or digits

JavaScript demo:

```js
const texts = ['abcde', '$#%^%abc'];
for (let text of texts) {
  console.log(text, '=>', text.replace(/^[^A-Za-z0-9+]+/, ''));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use match and groups

```js
const arr = [
  '<--%%-->abcde%aga',
  'abcde'
];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  // RegEx will group 3 parameters:
  // 1. Whole string
  // 2. Group before valid character
  // 3. Group after valid character
  const res = arr[i].match(/(.*?)([A-Za-z0-9\+]+.*$)/);

  // Log
  console.log(res);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If by *valid characters* you mean the [latin ASCII](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/miles/iso8859.html) characters, than you could :

```
/^[^a-z\d+]+/i
```

https://regex101.com/r/e8e1Cb/1